# Naming a variable within a loop

Tags: c#

I'm sorry if a similar question is posted on here. I could not find this answer anywhere, but perhaps I could have if I knew which key words to search.

I am trying to name a variable within a for loop or find an alternative way to solve my problem. Here is an example of what I am trying to do.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    string strName = "ImportedBody" + (i+1).ToString();
    IBody strName = model.GetEntity(strName) as IBody;
}
```

Essentially, my goal is to shorten:

```
IBody ImportedBody1 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody1") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody2 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody2") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody3 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody3") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody4 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody4") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody5 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody5") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody6 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody6") as IBody;
...
IBody ImportedBody100 = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody100") as IBody;
```

into a for loop or something that makes that quicker to write.

The name could also change if that is a problem. For example:

```
IBody ImportedBody1a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody1") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody2a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody2") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody3a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody3") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody4a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody4") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody5a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody5") as IBody;
IBody ImportedBody6a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody6") as IBody;
...
IBody ImportedBody100a = model.GetEntity("ImportedBody100") as IBody;
```

Here are a few notes on what this program is supposed to do. The program I am writing is interacting with a CAD program. If I import geometry into CAD then I have a list of bodies named "ImportedBody1, ImportedBody2, ImportedBody3, etc.. In order to edit that body within my c# program I have to get that from the CAD program using:

```
IBody Name = model.GetEntity(StringNameAsLabeledWithinCAD) as IBody;
```

Now I can do things like change the direction that it is facing:

```
Name.SetNormalDirection(0, 1, 0);
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for a collection, not individual variables.

Comment: Just use an array or a `List<IBody>` instead. Why do you think you actually need 100 variables?

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to name a variable within a for loop

The simple answer is... don't.

This is a job for collections (arrays, lists, etc.), not individual variables.  Something perhaps as simple as this:

```
var importedBodies = new List<IBody>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    var name = string.Format("ImportedBody{0}", i);
    var body = model.GetEntity(name) as IBody;

    importedBodies.Add(body);
}
```

After which you would have a collection called `importedBodies` which contains your 100 instances.  You can directly reference a specific one with an index, such as:

```
importedBodies[10] // The 11th imported body
```

Or you can even query the data to find elements based on other criteria:

```
importedBodies.Where(b => b.SomeProperty = "some value") // or any other expressions to query/transform the values
```

Comment: You're missing the token for `string.Format("ImportedBody", i)`.  I think you mean `string.Format("ImportedBody{0}", i)` :)